# USB flash security control

Tags: linux-mint, security, usb-device

I have just installed Linux Mint, and I want to secure it against USB-based viruses.

How can I block all USB flash devices except one that will be identified by an ID?

Answer (score 0):

A `udev` rule could solve your case, with something like

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", MODE="0000"
ACTION=="add", ATTRS{serial}=="6435004CB1E410A4084665E7",MODE="0666",GROUP="users"
```

where MODE stands for the usual Linux rights, and the serial of course the one of your device (`udevadm info --name=/dev/sdc1 --attribute-walk` to get the one of e.g. sdc1). 
Of course this will *not* protect you from [USB Killers](https://www.usbkill.com/).

**Disclaimer**: This is just an idea of how to possibly do this. Please test and check further e.g. starting with the [ArchWiki entry for udev](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#USB_flash_device)